# If the the adjacency matrix of a graph uniquely determines it up to isomorphism, then why is the isomorphism famous?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I hear about "The Graph Isomorphism Problem", and am a bit confused as to where the issue is. Isn't the adjacency matrix ( up to permutation ) unique for a graph up to isomorphism? Can't the problem be solved as easily as checking if two graphs have the same matrix up to permutations?

Comment: What makes you think that identifying whether matrices are the same up to permutation is an easy problem?

Comment: @MarkBennet Is it hard? I am not familiar with the computational complexity of this problem -- working with elementary matrices, this doesn't seem to be an issue, but I can imagine it growing with more columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to check if two graphs have the same adjacency matrix up to permutations (that is, if $A_1 = P^{-1}A_2 P$ for some permutation matrix $P$). But that's not easy.

To start with, maybe you should look at an example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you turn one matrix into the other? How do you tell? You probably shouldn't try all $8!$ permutation matrices, one at a time. But you also can't notice any useful features just by looking. (For small examples like this one, the representation as a graph diagram is probably *more* useful than the adjacency matrix.)

This is not to say that adjacency matrices aren't helpful to look at. For example, we can look at their eigenvalues; the first matrix has eigenvalues $$3,\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{17}-1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right),0$$
and the second has eigenvalues $$3,-\sqrt{2}-1,-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},-1,-1,1,\sqrt{2}-1$$ so they are not isomorphic. But this is not a foolproof method; it works most of the time, but the graph isomorphism problem was already easy *most* of the time, it's just hard in highly symmetric cases. Non-isomorphic graphs do exist whose adjacency matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Are there other invariant of similar matrices aside from eigenvalues that can help?

Comment: Looking at the eigenvalues and [eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392097) is generally how we go about using the adjacency matrices. Everything we could do for graphs we can also do for adjacency matrices, but eigenvalues and eigenvectors are the only things I'm aware of that's better to think about with adjacency matrices.